# Pyzipcode3 not finding ziptable

Tags: python, django, module

A process killed my terminal on a Mac and I created a new virtual environment. Pyzipcode3 is installed there.

However, whenever I try to run a command on it's zcdb. I get this error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: zip
```

Not sure how to fix this. This is what I have:

```
zcdb = ZipCodeDatabase()
path = settings.GEO_DB_PATH
```

This all runs, so the package seems to be installed, but it's not finding the db. The Settings GEO_DB_PATH has a path to the GeoCity2.mmdb.

```
>>> from pyzipcode import ZipCodeDatabase
>>> zcdb = ZipCodeDatabase()
>>> zipcode = zcdb[54115]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyzipcode/__init__.py", line 108, in __getitem__
    zip_code = self.get(str(zip_code))
  File "~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyzipcode/__init__.py", line 105, in get
    return format_result(self.conn_manager.query(ZIP_QUERY, (zip_code,)))
  File "~/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyzipcode/__init__.py", line 35, in query
    cursor.execute(sql, args)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: zip
>>>
```

Comment: _but it's not finding the db_ It does find the database, but not the `zip` table inside the database.  Can you use a database viewer application to verify if that table is present?

Comment: It was working before. I didn't touch that db, so it must be there. Let me check.